# Быстро посчитать количество цифр в строке

Tags: delphi

Как можно быстро посчитать количество цифр в строке?

Так же хочу узнать плюсы, и минусы моего варианта (где можно ускорить/что поменять)

```pascal
function Digits(S: String): Integer;
var
  C: Char;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for C := '0' to '9' do Inc(Result, S.CountChar(C));
end;
```

Comment: `CountChar` что за функция такая?

Comment: @slippyk [System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.CountChar](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.CountChar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот, достаточно быстрый вариант:

```
function DigitCount(const AStr: string): Integer;
var
  P: PChar;
begin
  Result := 0;
  P := PChar(AStr);
  while P^ <> #0 do begin
    if (P^ >= '0') and (P^ <= '9') then begin
      Inc(Result);
    end;
    Inc(P);
  end;
end;
```

Недостаток вашего кода заключается в том, что вы 10 раз (!) вызываете функцию (что само по себе накладно), которая каждый раз сканирует строку в поисках одного символа. А код выше, проходит по строке всего один раз, т.е. делает работу в 10 раз быстрее.

Comment: А как посчитать, какой способ быстрей?

Comment: @Legended Вызвать функцию несколько тысяч раз и замерить время выполнения, с использованием [TStopwatch](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch): [How to calculate elapsed time of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16984761/)

Comment: @Legended Собственно, вот [сравнение](https://gist.github.com/zedxxx/6baf6e0467ae1e60237fc3a194f47ec4) всех трёх вариантов. Получилось не в 10 раз быстрее, но около того.

Comment: Спасибо! кстати, а с помощью **asm** вставки реально ли еще ускорить?

Comment: @Legended А вы посмотрите какой код генерирует Delphi и подумайте, сможете ли написать лучше и есть ли там что оптимизировать (по-моему, нет).

Comment: Просто мне надо максимально быстро, потому и спросил.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Digits(S: String): Integer;
var
  i: integer;
  Count: integer;
  NumCode: set of '0'..'9';
begin
  NumCode := ['0'..'9'];
  Count := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin  
    if S[i] in NumCode then
      Inc(Count);
  end;
  Result := Count;
end;
```

Comment: Вашу функцию можно ускорить минимум в два раза. См. [тут](https://gist.github.com/zedxxx/6baf6e0467ae1e60237fc3a194f47ec4) (функция Digits_2).

Comment: @zed исключительно из любопытства - а откуда 2 раза? Здесь - накладные расходы на заполнение NumCode и работу с Count вместо сразу Result (то есть - мизер). И вроде всё... `CharInSet` из Digits_2 - инлайнится и становится тем же самым  `S[i] in ...`

Comment: @kami Видимо, и этого достаточно. До оптимизации было 305 ms, после 133 ms.